# Force root xml element to be array on json conversion

Tags: json, xml, json.net

I am using below (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json) to force XML nodes to be an array when converted to JSON:

```
<person xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json' id='1'>
  <name>Alan</name>
  <url>http://www.google.com</url>
  <role json:Array='true'>Admin</role>
</person>
```

and what I get is

```
 {
   "person": {
     "@id": "1",
     "name": "Alan",
     "url": "http://www.google.com",
     "role": [
       "Admin"
     ]
   }
 }
```

What I wanted is

```
 {
   "person": [
      {
     "@id": "1",
     "name": "Alan",
     "url": "http://www.google.com",
     "role": [
       "Admin"
     ]
    }
   ]
 }
```

Is it possible to force array on root node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the result you desire by:

1. Adding `json:Array='true'` to the root element `<person>`.

   Since you are already adding this attribute to `<role>` adding it to the root element as well should not be a burden.
2. Loading the XML into an `XDocument` (or `XmlDocument`) and converting *the document itself* rather than just the root element `XDocument.Root`.

Thus:

```
var xml = @"<person xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json' id='1' json:Array='true'>
  <name>Alan</name>
  <url>http://www.google.com</url>
  <role json:Array='true'>Admin</role>
</person>";

var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDocument, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Generates the JSON you want:

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "@id": "1",
      "name": "Alan",
      "url": "http://www.google.com",
      "role": [
        "Admin"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But the following does not:

```
var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDocument.Root, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

A similar result obtains using `XmlDocument`, in which only the following works as desired:

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);

var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDocument, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

I confirmed this on both Json.NET 10.0.1 and Json.NET 12.0.1. It's a bit mysterious why serializing the document vs. its root element should make a difference, you might create an [issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) for Newtonsoft asking why it should matter.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QP3JgA).

Comment: Yup..it worked, Root vs Document is what is causing the issue. Thanks a ton for the quick response.