# JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode() removes child nodes with same name as array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an XML representation of a JSON string that contains an array and that array contains a child node with the same name of the array. When I call the JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode() method to convert that XML representation into a JSON string, it removes the inner child node with the same name as the array.

For example, I have the following XML representation of the JSON object:

```
<location xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json" json:Array="true">
    <location>
        <name>Name of location.location 1</name>
    </location>
</location>
```

When I call JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode() with this XML, the resulting JSON string removes the inner  element resulting in this:

```
"location": [
    {
        "name": "Name of location.location 1"
    }
]
```

However, I would expect to get this JSON string preserving the inner element:

```
"location": [
    {
        "location": {
            "name": "Name of location.location 1"
        }
    }
]
```

Here is some example code on how to reproduce the issue:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<location xmlns:json=\"http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json\" json:Array=\"true\"><location><name> Name of location.location 1</name></location></location>");
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

Is there a way to change this behavior in JSON.NET or otherwise work around it? I am not able to change the structure of the JSON/XML as it is defined by a third party.

Comment: Can you share the actual code you are using, including the call to `JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode()`?  This might or might not be related to [Force root xml element to be array on json conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53783053/3744182), which depends whether you are passing the `XmlDocument` or `XmlDocument.DocumentElement` into the conversion method.

Comment: Also, your XML sample isn't well-formed; if I upload it to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ I get an error `The prefix "json" for attribute "json:Array" associated with an element type "location" is not bound.`  Might you please [edit] your question to share a full [mcve] with code and well-formed, complete XML?

Comment: Thanks -- added sample code and fixed the XML by adding the json namespace prefix definition.